# Bold and italic command is not working

Tags: xetex, formatting, luatex

I've tried \bfseries and \textbf{} for the bold and \textit{} or \emph, but neither change the text. I'm really not sure what can I do. I'll put some examples of the code I have.

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize \bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize \bfseries}
```

this one will put in normal size the title but not in bold.

```
{\noindent\bfseries{Key words:}\textit{ abc, abs, abc}}\\ 

{\noindent\bfseries{Abstract: }\textit{\blindtext }}
```

Again, the other commands works but not `italic` or the `bold`.

As far as I know, I'm using all packages necessary. Thank you for the help!

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), then we could check if some packages are missing.

Comment: Perhaps the font you're using doesn't support those. Which font are you using? Site note: Note that `\bfseries` doesn't take an argument, the correct syntax is not `\bfseries{foo}` but `{\bfseries foo}`.

Comment: Just edit to include some of the packages i'm using. The font is Times New Roman. I've tried both ways to be honest just to check

Comment: It is impossible to debug fragments, make a small but complete one paragraph document that does not give the fonts you expect, than people can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: but never do `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`  Do not use fontenc with luatex or xetex.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem! Btw , just for information, why shouldn't use  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} wiht luatex or xetex?

Comment: @RebecaNunesMarini the point about luatex/xetex is they use system Unicode fonts with thousands of characters in each font. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` tells latex to use fonts with T1 encoding that has at most 256 characters in each font.

Answer (score 4):

Never do

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Do not use `fontenc` with luatex or xetex, with those engines you want to use Unicode (TU encoding) not the 256-character tex-specific T1 encoding. TU is already set up by default (in current formats or by `fontspec` package even in older formats) so you do not need to specify the encoding.