# Creating bold and italic text not working with a custom font?

Tags: fonts, formatting, bold, italic

```
\textit{\textbf{Text here}}
```

and

```
\textit{Text here}
```

is my code.

I am using the font which can be downloaded for free from: https://sansforgetica.rmit/

However creating bold and italic text for this font in LaTeX seems to not be working, no compiler errors or anything to that effect.

Utilising

```
\section{Text here}
```

does work though with this font and highlights the section title in bold using this font.

I know it is definitely not the font because I have tried it in word and it works fine when creating bold and italic text using this font inside word.

The full version of my code, without these two attempts in can be viewed at: https://github.com/Some-T/MemorisationDocumentLaTeXTemplate

I have tried to put in between in

> main.tex

file on here, `\begin{flushleft}` and `\end{flushleft}`

I have tried this with these two elements removed to no avail.

I am at a loss, how can I make bold and italics perform in LaTeX on a custom font, what am I doing wrong in my code in its entirety?

I have gone through all similar answers on here and only one that comes close is: [Bold and italic command is not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402552/bold-and-italic-command-is-not-working) but I have also tried everything here to no avail.

I have tried to compile this code in XeLatex and LuaLaTeX on overleaf.com
Additional evidence relating to the font actually having bold and italics done in Microsoft word 2019: [image: https://i.gyazo.com/1592b9659cc2851352d78d9357abc3f1.gif]

Attempted fake bold:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the font has bold italic characters at all, i.e. is there a version of the font that has bold italic symbols?

Comment: Just added a gif to my question with evidence of it in word with the exact same font.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be bold and italic... by OMG, do you really want to use this font? ;-)

Comment: It actually works for me, as in being able to read the font (not my issue) I need to remember this stuff haha. Some others may not be inclined to utilise such a difficult to read font...

Comment: The problem is not reading it -- it's extraordinarily ugly, in my point of view. If I want to annoy readers, I would use such a font ;-)

Comment: That word can slant and embolden the font doesn't proof that italic and bold glyphs exist. Such things can be faked.  See e.g fakebold in the fontspec docu.

Comment: Although this is going off topic a bit, I don't mind but not sure if it is against the rules... if you know of a better font that is easier on the eye but allows for improvements in information retention I would be very grateful to hear of one, I looked for ages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have added `\fontspec[AutoFakeBold=1.5]{SansForgetica-Regular.otf}` and 
`\fontspec[BoldFeatures={FakeBold=1.5}]{SansForgetica-Regular.otf}` to the top of my code using the XeLaTeX engine but it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the features by hand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{SansForgetica}[
  Path=./,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  BoldFont=*-Regular,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=3},
  ItalicFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3},
  BoldItalicFont=*-Regular,
  BoldItalicFeatures={FakeBold=3,FakeSlant=0.3},
]

\begin{document}

Abc def

\textit{Abc def}

\textbf{Abc def}

\textit{\textbf{Abc def}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I use `Path=./` in order to load the font from a working directory, as I don't want to mix the beast with my system fonts. Your setup may differ.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I learned a lot from this. The upvote does not show because I have less than 15 reputation but I still think it counts. I added one amendment to include: `\setmainfont{[SansForgetica-Regular.otf]}` because it would not compile on mine unless I added this with XeLaTeX

Comment: @SomeT I don't think that amendment is right. You should rather modify the `Path` or remove it altogether, if the font is installed as a system font.

Comment: I am using overleaf.com, so I think because it is in the cloud I am not and cannot setting the Path locally, if by path you mean for example 'environment variables' in Windows 10? I mean at least its here in the comments anyway for anyone else who uses overleaf and comes across this.

Comment: @SomeT I don't use Overleaf, mainly because I want to control my TeX environment and not depend on other people's choices about what updates they deem worthwhile.

Comment: Yeah, I mainly use it for studies to be honest, and I change devices day to day a lot so overleaf works better for me. I did used to have a local environment set up but when I started using more and more devices this became a pain to manage.

Comment: I think fontspec also has AutoFakeBold and AutoFakeSlant to simplify this case a little